# Icons in jsf do not appear

Tags: html, css

I am developing a java application using the JSF I put phone icons and message envelope but they do not appear, already tried to put them in the   tag but it did not appear

```
<Li> <i class = "fa fa-phone"> </ i> +2 95 01 88 821 </ li>
<Li> <i class = "fa fa-envelope"> </ i> info@domain.com </ li>
```

How it should look like:

[image: image 1]

[image: image2]

UPDATE

I inserted the font

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

But still the icons do not appear

[icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMrXK.jpg)

Hierarchy of files
[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6njF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You have to remove extra spaces:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+2 95 01 88 821</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@domain.com</li>
```

Tag names are usually in lowercase.
Hope you have CSS describing your classes `fa`, `fa-envelope` and `fa-phone`...

**Update**
As I understand from your comments you have no CSS and font Awesome for your HTML. So you have to add them.

As @cjslv recommended, please look at http://fontawesome.io
Also I'd suggest you to refresh your [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) skills.

Comment: I removed the extra spaces but continued the same error

Comment: Have you included CSS and font "Awesome" to your page?

Comment: Need css and font for icons ? Where do I go to the  font and css?

Comment: I inserted the font But still the icons do not appear

Comment: @Felipe, I do not see `fonts` folder in your files hierarchy. Where did you add the font files (`.eot, .ttf, .woff` etc)? You have to add `fonts` folder with the font files to the same folder where `css` folder is placed.

Comment: @felipe: what tutorial did you use?